# Shorten Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a feeling this Python code could be shortened greatly, but I almost always tend to fall back to writing C-style layout. What is the best way to shorten it, in your opinion? Readability is a bonus, not a requirement.

```
def compfiles(file1, file2):
    linecnt = 0
    for line1 in open(file1):
        line1 = line1.strip()
        hit = False
        for line2 in open(file2):
            line2 = line2.strip()
            if line2 == line1:
                hit = True
                break
        if not hit:
            print("Miss: file %s contains '%s', but file %s does not!" % (file1, line1, file2))
        linecnt += 1
    print("%i lines compared between %s and %s." % (linecnt, file1, file2))

fn = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
compfiles(fn[0], fn[1])
compfiles(fn[1], fn[0])
```

Comment: If the code works, the proper place to ask how to improve it is on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would really open the same file over and over in C without closing it or just seeking to the beginning? I thought not. I'd try finding a better algorithm (not O(n**2)) before bothering to shorten it.

Comment: @gnibbler: quick and dirty hack over 600 lines, cache takes care of it, runs in <1 second, n.p. :)

Comment: Only 600 lines? just read the files into sets (for sensible values of line). And use set operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is extremely inefficient because you `open` the second file inside the loop iterating over the first file. Just read the second file into a list (or better yet, a `set` which gives you on average `O(1)` lookup time) and use the `in` operator. Also, your `linecnt` variable just counts the number of lines in file1 - you can just read the lines into a list and call `len` on this list to get the same number:

```
def compfiles(file1, file2):
    lines1 = [l.strip() for l in open(file1).read().split("\n")]
    lines2 = set([l.strip() for l in open(file2).read().split("\n")])
    for line in lines1:
        if not line in lines2:
            print("Miss: file %s contains '%s', but file %s does not!" % (file1, line, file2))
    print("%i lines compared between %s and %s." % (len(lines1), file1, file2))
```

Comment: This is still O(n**2) comparisons

Comment: @gnibbler I guess file2 could be turned into a set which would make the lookup `O(1)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
def compfiles(file1, file2):
    with open(file1) as fin:
        set1 = set(fin)
    with open(file2) as fin:
        set2 = set(fin)
    ... # do some set operations
```

If the files have duplicate lines or the order is important, iterate over file1

```
def compfiles(file1, file2):
    with open(file2) as fin:
        set2 = set(fin)
    with open(file1) as fin:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if line not in set2:
                print("Miss: file %s contains '%s', but file %s does not!" % (file1, line1, file2))           
        print("%i lines compared between %s and %s." % (i+1, file1, file2))
```

Comment: While this would work, it wouldn't show the exact behaviour as OPs code if file1 contains duplicate lines.

Comment: True. It might work better to read file2 into a set and iterate over file1